# writing an sql query?

Tags: mysql

I'm having 2 tables

table Items Table (this table holds all items I'm having)

```
itemId
---------
Item1
Item2
Item3
Item4
Item5

table 2 users_item relation 
UserId  || ItemId
1  || Item1
1  || Item2
```

userId one has stored 2 items Item1,Item2.
Now I want to write a query on table1 (Items table) so that it displays all items which user1 has NOT chosen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select itemid from Items where itemid not in 
(select itemid from users_item where userid = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select itemid 
from Items i
left join (select ItemId from users_item where userId = 1)chosen on chosen.ItemId = i.itemId
where chosen.ItemId is null;
```